# SQL Server Query returning inconsistent results

Tags: sql-server, google-analytics, ssms

We have a website that is load balanced across 2 servers. This accommodates our running traffic 90% of time, however we occasionally large spikes in traffic when we go on sale with particular products.

To handle this, we a have a waiting room application sitting on the gateway server. This assigns each user an unique session id for the waiting room.

If the number of sessions currently on the site is below the stated threshold, then it lets the user through, otherwise they are sent to holding page where they can see there position in the queue. The session is maintained by javascript function on every page that pings the waiting room application every 15 seconds.

If a session misses 3 pings in a row, then it assumed the user has left the site and their session is expired so the next user can enter the site. This appears to work really well, however I've recently noticed some inconsistencies when using SQL Server Management Studio to to view the current number of users on the site.

For example, Google Analytics will be reporting 200 users on the site, which is below the threshold. When I run the script below it will sometimes report all 200 users being in the site but more often not will only report around 100.

```
SELECT Count([id]) AS In_Site
FROM [WaitingRoom].[dbo].[queueUsers]
WHERE [status] = 2

SELECT Count([id]) AS Waiting
FROM [WaitingRoom].[dbo].[queueUsers]
WHERE [status] = 1
```

Database is SQL Server 2016 Express and using SQL Server Management Studio 17

Any ideas why sometimes SQL doesn't appear to return all users correctly?

Comment: As a general rule never blame the database, if you see inconsistent results is either a problem of your query, the process that populate the data or simply bad data (this is the database version of "there is an error in the compiler").

Comment: I believe the database is acting correctly, but it appears the query isn't returning the right data. However it's a fairly straight forward query an d can't see any issues with it, hence my confusion.

Comment: What I mean is in cases like this you can just rule out "database returning incorrect results". In your case since you are using a trivial query you can also rule out a bad constructed query. Then your problem is not "I get incorrect results" but instead "maybe I have bad/inconsistent data in my DB".

Answer (score 1):

This probably has more to do with the discrepancy of what Google Analytics classifies as active users and what your code does.

Looking at their [metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6171863?hl=en#metrics) information:

> **How the metric values relate to your date range**
>
> The metrics in the report are relative to the last day in the date range you are using for the report. For example, if your date range is January 1 to January 30:
>
> - **1-Day Active Users**: the number of unique users who initiated sessions on your site or app on January 30 (the last day of your date range).

So reading that, I'd assume that is users that have been on today, rather than actively on the site.

Comment: The number from analytics is from the real time overview page of current users. I initially assumed it was simple discrepancy issue but the the results from the SQL query change from 200 to 100 and back again in a matter of seconds. This seems very unusual to me.

Comment: how does your code work exactly? If they aren't on the tab actively, would that count as inactive? also why not use IIS session timeouts instead and configure it to suitable value?

Comment: As long as the page is open and the javascript is still running then they'll still be marked as active. So even if they're not currently viewing that tab, they would still be marked as active. I didn't use IIS session timeouts as the waiting room uses a custom rewrite provider on the gateway before directing the user either to the holding page, which is also on the gateway or forwarding them on the webfarm. I wasn't sure how reliably the IIS sessions would be maintained with this behavior so was easier to manage the sessions myself. Also it gives me the ability to kick users if I need to.